# How can I cast my command object to its generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I have an command object which may implements ICommand but may implement a generic interface `IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate>`.

```
public interface IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate> : ICommand where TAggregate : IAggregate
{
    TAggregate Entity { get; set; }
}
```

Which I am testing like this:

```
    var isIUpdateAggregateCommand = command.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
        x.IsGenericType &&
        x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IUpdateAggregateCommand<>));
```

If it does implement the interface how can I cast it to the specific type e.g. If it implements `IUpdateAggregateCommand<Person>` how can I cast command to `IUpdateAggregateCommand<Person>`?

I need to be able to set the value of Entity

### Update

I am inside a decorator and I don't know the type of the aggregate that I would need to cast it to. So I need to figure out what type it is and then cast it to that

Comment: If you don't know what type it is, how do you know you'll be able to set `Entity`?

Comment: I can get a repository that returns me instances of TAggregate once I know its type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo SetAggregateInternalMethod = typeof(Extensions)
        .GetMethod("SetAggregateInternal", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static void SetAggregateInternal<TAggregate>(object item, TAggregate value) where TAggregate : IAggregate
    {
        var aggregateCommand = item as IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate>;
        if (aggregateCommand != null)
            aggregateCommand.Entity = value;
    }

    public static void TrySetAggregate(object item, IAggregate value)
    {
        SetAggregateInternalMethod
            .MakeGenericMethod(value.GetType())
            .Invoke(null, new[] { item, value });
    }
}
```

You can also increase performance by using caching and compiled [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Can't you convert directly?

```
IUpdateAggregateCommand<MyAggregate> updateAggregateCommand = command as IUpdateAggregateCommand<MyAggregate>;
if (updateAggregateCommand != null)
{
    updateAggregateCommand.Entity = ...
}
```

MyAggregate is a type defined by you (obviously).

**Edit:**

I don't think it is possible to scan for implemented interfaces and simply cast to them. Reflection may be the best solution for this kind of job. You can scan for implemented interfaces and then make a dynamic method invocation to set the entity. Then again you need to know the type of the entity and instantiate or set it accordingly. Doesn't sound very type safe.

What are you trying to accomplish? How is your decorator implemented? Maybe there are other solutions to solve your problem if this approach is cumbersome.

Comment: Sorry updated question. You are right but I don't currently know the type of TAggregate

Comment: In a decorator for command handler. I am looking up an aggregate in a repository based on type of command message. Then after command has run pass aggregate back to repository.  Basically removes any need for persistence in command handler so increasing testabilty and reducing code dupe

Answer (score 2):

Could you just check to see if your command variable is of the type?  If when this command object was instantiated, it inherited from it, it will return true.

```
if(command is IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate>)
```

Then you'll just:

```
var newCommand = ((IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate>)command);
```

or

```
var newCommand = command as IUpdateAggregateCommand<TAggregate>;
```

---

With your update that you don't know what to cast it to, you could continue using Reflection which is slow, or do `If, Else If` checks which is fast, readable and you're going to need to use some special property/functionality anyways that is unique to this type.
If you're looking for a ***common property***, then you need to make a more generic Interface that they all inherit from, at which point you don't need If/Else If anyways.

---

Second edit:
Are you looking for a concept like the below?  This allows me to get an item from a list based on its type, as well as to return it based on its generic type.

```
    List<IMockEvent> events = new List<IMockEvent>();
    public IMockEvent<K> GetMockEvent<T, K>()
    {
        return events.First(t => t is T) as IMockEvent<K>;
    }
    public void Add(IMockEvent evt)
    {
        events.Add(new MockStatusUpdate());
    }
```

where classes are defined as

```
public class EMockStatusUpdated : StatusUpdated, IMockEvent<string> { }
public interface IMockEvent<T> : IMockEvent { }
public interface IMockEvent { }
```

Comment: Sorry updated question. You are right but I don't currently know the type of TAggregate

Comment: Any idea the reflection to do it? It will happen at most once per web request

Comment: @GraemeMiller I added what I think you're getting at now, though from my current usage and not customized to you yet. And reflection is still fast if you do it once, though it is slower than a quick `is` check, to the human it is still negligible - just try to avoid it when you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IAggregate { }
public class Person : IAggregate { }

public interface ICommand { }
public class BaseCommand : ICommand { }

public interface IUpdateAggregateCommand<out T> : ICommand where T : IAggregate
{
    T GetEntity();
}

public class UpdateAggregateCommand<T> : IUpdateAggregateCommand<T> where T : IAggregate
{
    private T entity;
    public void SetEntity(T t) { this.entity = t; }

    public T GetEntity() { return this.entity; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var command = new BaseCommand();
        var obj = command as IUpdateAggregateCommand<IAggregate>;
        if (obj != null)
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetEntity().GetType());

        var command1 = new UpdateAggregateCommand<Person>();
        command1.SetEntity(new Person());
        var obj1 = command1 as IUpdateAggregateCommand<IAggregate>;
        if (obj1 != null)
            Console.WriteLine(obj1.GetEntity().GetType());
    }
}
```